# What causes this failure to get the data from the next row in a MySQL table, with Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on an **[online newspaper/blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/twigPress/)** with **CodeIgniter 3.1.8** and Bootstrap 4.

At the bottom of the *single post* view, I want to add a *link to the next post* (as well as one to the previous post). For this, I need to get the data (slug, title, etc), of the next post (row in the `posts` table).

For this purpose, I have added this method to my **Posts_model** model:

```
/* Next post */
public function get_next_post($slug) {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('slug' => $slug));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = $query->next_row();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

In the controller I have:

```
public function post($slug) {
  //more code
  $data['post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_post($slug);
  $data['next_post'] = $this->Posts_model->get_next_post($slug);
  print_r($data['next_post']);
  //more code
}
```

---

**EDIT:** In the **Posts_model**, I now have:

```
/* Next post */
public function get_next_post($slug) {
    $query = $this->db->get('posts');
    $row_index = 6;
    $data = $query->row_array($row_index);     
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = $query->next_row();
        return $data;
    }
}

/* Prev post */
public function get_prev_post($slug) {
    $query = $this->db->get('posts');
    $row_index = 6;
    $data = $query->row_array($row_index);     
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = $query->previous_row();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

That means that if I could get the current post's index by slug, I could replace this hardcoded index of the 7th post - `$row_index = 6` - and the problem would be solved.

How do I do that?

Comment: can you please roll back the edit, as it is actually becoming a new question and my earlier answer might not make sense anymore as you use my answers code now in your edited question. Please ask a new question!

Comment: I've done the rollback, please ask a new question with the new problem

Comment: yes, but if someone new comes to read the post, they might think that I just copied your code into my answer! there is a post on Meta, which says not to change substantially a question once it was answered.

Comment: @Actually no, because I have specified "EDIT".

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions and btw. did you try the code I wrote in chat?

Comment: @Raz `$query->next_row()` looks like a misunderstanding of functionality.  Are you expecting the method to magically know which row comes _after_ the row matching your slug?  That is not how it works.  Orders are not predictable unless you specify the order in your query.  I recommend only making one trip to the db, fetch the three rows only -- this might be 3 union'ed queries in one, pass all three rows back to the controller.

Comment: @Raz You cannot rely on the db's row order.  You need to have an explicit ORDER BY to know which row is previous and which is next.  I assume you cannot use `slug` for this.  Is there an id row that will reliably tell what os previous and what is next?  (going to bed now)

Comment: @mickmackusa I want to know the index of the current post, reliably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Your_model.php    

...

public function getPost($slug) {
    $this->db->where('slug', $slug);
    return $this->db->get('posts_table')->row_array();
}

public function getPrevPost($currentPostId) {
    $this->db->where('id <', $currentPostId);
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');        
    $this->db->limit(1);
    return $this->db->get('posts_table')->row_array();
}

public function getNextPost($currentPostId) {
    $this->db->where('id >', $currentPostId);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    return $this->db->get('posts_table')->row_array();
}


// Yourcontroller.php

...

public function getPost($slug) {
    $post = $this->your_model->getPost($slug);
    
    $data = [
            'thePost' => $post,
             ...
            'prevPost' => $this->your_model->getPrevPost($post['id']),
            'nextPost' => $this->your_model->getNextPost($post['id']),
             ...
            ];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: this post answers the original question. In the meantime below code was used in an edit by OP.**

you need to return a result of your query: `$data = $query->row_array();`

And `get_where()` is limiting the record-set to one record, hence there is no next record. You need to return the complete record-set with `$this->db->get('posts')`. In case you know the row_number (e.g.: 5) of the row containing `$slug`, you can point to it. The next_row shown, is row number 6.

```
public function get_next_post($slug) {
    $query = $this->db->get('posts');  // querying the whole data-set
    $data = $query->row_array(5);      // the missing line
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = $query->next_row();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

now you should get your next row (if exists), see [Result Rows](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html?highlight=next_row#result-rows)

Comment: `print_r($data['next_post']);` still does not return admitting.

Comment: All the data on the single post view, including the current post data (id, title, etc), but nothing from the next post.

Comment: did you check, if there is a next row?

Comment: Yes, there is. Also, `{{ next_post.id }}` in the view (Twig) is empty.

Comment: try with `$this->db->get('posts');`

Comment: I've update my answer, hope it make sense and works out

Comment: Actually, getting the index of the current post's row (in the table), instead of `$data = $query->row_array(5)` would help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228358/discussion-between-vickel-and-razvan-zamfir).